# Property attributes 'nonnull' and 'weak' are mutually exclusive

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7

Recently I upgraded my Xcode to version 7 - XCode 7.0. Now I am getting this message to every IBOutlet of mine:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak, nonnull) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

***Property attributes 'nonnull' and 'weak' are mutually exclusive***

Whant can I do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The whole point of `weak` is that the property becomes `nil` when the object is deallocated. The whole point of `nonnull` is that the property can never be `nil`. That's why you can't apply both.

Either make your property `strong nonnull` or just `weak`.

Comment: Nice. I am studying about Generics and Nullability and the way I found for now is put just `weak`. Thanks!

Comment: The property in your question has nothing to do with generics. It's an outlet.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, I thought I should add a second answer here.  Pedantically, weak and nonnull are not truly mutually exclusive if a property has custom getters and setters.  For example:

```
@property(...) Foo *foo;

- (Foo *)foo {
  if (_foo) return _foo;
  return [Foo sharedInstance];
}

- (void)setFoo:(Foo *)newFoo {
  assert(newFoo);
  _foo = newFoo;
}
```

But there's also no good reason to allow this, because there's no good reason to not allow setting the variable to nil to reset it to the default value.  And when you do that, you specify the `null_resettable` attribute.